# How to use custom variables in an Activiti task

Tags: activiti

**Problem**

I have several Activiti task types, the base types are `ServiceTask` and `UserTask`.

Some `ServiceTask` types are Java implementations, each of them different. Then there are others.

I'd like to distinguish them in my code.

**Question**

Is it possible to store some custom attributes / properties in the tasks and if so, how?

Example:
A `ServiceTask` that implements simple Logging functionality should have a property "TYPE" with the value "LOGGING" which I can then query later.

I tried using `FieldExtension`, but when I run the workflow, Activiti throws the error:

```
org.activiti.engine.ActivitiIllegalArgumentException: Field definition uses unexisting field 'TYPE'
```

Same happens for `CustomProperty`.

Of course I could solve that by declaring the field in the Java class, but I need a solution that works also for non Java service tasks and for user tasks. Or better yet if possible for all flow elements.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

You can define fields in XML/Designer:

```
<serviceTask id="javaService"
    name="Java service invocation"
    activiti:class="org.activiti.examples.bpmn.servicetask.ToUppercase">
    <extensionElements>
      <activiti:field name="text" stringValue="Hello World" />
  </extensionElements>
</serviceTask>
```

If you want to access the field in Java code you can do it like that:

```
public class ToUppercase implements JavaDelegate {
    Expression text;

  public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {
    String value = (String) text.getValue(execution);
    value = value.toUpperCase();
    execution.setVariable("upperedText", value);
  }

}
```

If you want to access variables in UserTask you have to implement TaskListener instead of JavaDelegate.

Comment: Thank you, but as I wrote in the question, I already know about that and would need a solution that's also for other flow elements.